# Ignoring page load in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I make Selenium (chromedriver) ignore a page load c#?

Specifically, I am trying to upload a few files and when the upload button is clicked, the page will become busy while upload is taking place. At this point, I want to open a new tab to upload another file.

The problem is once the page is busy, the script will pause and wait at that page. If I add a "SetPageLoadTimeout" of 10 seconds and try-catch to ignore the timeout exception, the script will continue but the current page will stop "loading", stopping the upload as well.

Is there any way I can open a new tab and continue without stopping the current busy page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create driver with unstable webdriver.load.strategy:

```
      DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      caps.setCapability("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

[webdriver.load.strategy](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/DesiredCapabilities.wiki) capability set driver not to wait for page load, offering you to do it yourself.

```
webdriver.load.strategy || string || Experimental API. Defines different strategies for how long to wait until a page is loaded. Values: unstable, conservative. Defaults to conservative.
```

Problem is you can't switch this option runtime - and you will be with it at all the times, and it can break down your other code.

2) If you want to make other tab, why not to create other browser? You can create several driver objects, and initialise them at same time. They will look as two separate browsers. And you can do parallel task with them at the same time.